# How can I use for loop to remove match from a list?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a Go Fish card game in Python, but I'm having trouble with one of the first steps. Each time a card is drawn, I want it to look for a match in the hand and remove both if it does. Essentially, "card" pops a card from the deck, the "for" loop iterates through the hand for a match. If it finds a match, then the card in the hand is removed and card is never added to the hand (disappears really.) Through the use of the dubugger, I discovered the script is automatically putting the popped card into the hand just as it reaches the "for" loop. I have two questions: Why does it work the way? And how can I make this work? Thank You!

p.s. I also noticed it struggles to compare face cards, which I represent as 'A','K','Q', and 'J'. If you have a better way around this, I am open to suggestions, but otherwise I can figure that one out.

```
def draw_card(hand):
    # Handles very first card drawn. Adds card if hand is empty
    card = list.pop(cards)
    print('card is',card)
    for i in hand:
        print('Hand is: ',hand)
        if i == card:
            print(i,card)
            print('This value will be removed: ',i)
            hand.remove(i)
        else:
            hand.append(card)
    return hand
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to iterate through the hand, just use the *in* keyword to see if the hand contains the popped card.  Also, what is `cards`? I removed it from pop() argument.  In this way, it just pops the last card from the deck.  Finally, never use *list* as a name for a list (it's reserved as a Python keyword).  I renamed it deck.

```
def draw_card(hand):
    # Handles very first card drawn. Adds card if hand is empty
    card = deck.pop()
    print('card is',card)
    if card in hand:
        print('This value will be removed: ',card)
        hand.remove(card)
    else:
        hand.append(card)
    return hand
```

Comment: I assume that "cards" is a list of integers and strings. That would explain the struggle mentioned in the post scriptum. It is important to mention the presence of reserved keywords. However, "list" was not used as a variable name but as a class reference to call the pop method. One might want to add that the pop method removes and returns the last list item by default. To modify this behaviour, one has to specify the index argument (e.g. deck.pop(index=0), to get the first item).